# SSRS: filter parameter passed to sub-report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Let's say I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID | Name
1  | John
2  | Bill
3  | Mike (Inactive)
4  | Jim
```

I'm using that as a parameter in my main report, where the `ID` is the `Value` and `Name` is the `Label`. This works as wanted.

Now I have a subreport which is accessed by pressing a field on the main report. The field has an action set to go the the wanted subreport. At this moment, it is also passing all parameters.

This is what it looks like:

[image: action tab]

However, I want it to exclude all names that contain `Inactive`. I tried it by using expression such as

```
NOT(Parameters!pEmployee_List.Value LIKE "*Inactive*")
```

But when I pass to the subreport from the main, it gives the error that no parameter is selected.

Any ideas, suggestions?

**EDIT:**

After being pointed out by Stefan Steiger, I confused `value` en `label`. I would like the filter to work on `value` because it's being used a lot already on the subreport.

My second attempt:

```
=IIF(Parameters!pEmployee_List.Label LIKE "*Inactive*", "0", Parameters!pEmployee_List.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The property "Value" searches in the `ID`, if you want to search in `Name`, you need to use the property "Label":

```
NOT(Parameters!pEmployee_List.Label LIKE "*Inactive*")
```

Comment: You're correct. I had totally missed that. (+1 for that) However I would like not to change any setting in the subreport and keep searching on the `ID` `Value`.
I have edited my Question